# how do I convert this styled-components code using TSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm new to TS, so this code might looks ugly :(

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

interface defineProps {
  readonly left?: boolean;
  readonly right?: boolean;
}

interface WrapperProps {
  readonly width: number;
  readonly maxWidth: number;
  defineWrapper: (props: defineProps) => string;
// maybe this code above is the problem?
}

const defineWrapper = (props: defineProps) => {
  if (props.right) return rightWrapper;
  if (props.left) return leftWrapper;
};

const rightWrapper = css`
  border-left: 1px solid ${(props) => props.theme.colors.ink40};
`;

const leftWrapper = css`
  border-right: 1px solid ${(props) => props.theme.colors.ink40};
`;

export const Wrapper = styled.div<WrapperProps>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: ${({ width }) => width && `${width}vw`};
  max-width: ${({ maxWidth }) => `${maxWidth}px`};
  height: 100vh;

  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.body50};

  ${defineWrapper}  //  ERROR!
`;
```

I've read some blog posts, but there's nothing like this. 
I want to keep `${defineWrapper}` code, cuz I used these thing quite often in JSX.

any helps would be appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about working with styled-system for the width props ? Please read about it in [here](https://styled-system.com/)

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';
import { width, maxWidth, WidthProps } from 'styled-system';

interface ContainerProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  readonly left?: boolean;
  readonly right?: boolean;
}

type Props = ContainerProps &
  WidthProps & {
    children: ReactNode;
  };

const defineWrapper = (props: ContainerProps) => {
  if (props.right) return rightWrapper;
  if (props.left) return leftWrapper;
};

const rightWrapper = css`
  border-left: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.ink40};
`;

const leftWrapper = css`
  border-right: 1px solid ${props => props.theme.colors.ink40};
`;

const Container = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  ${width};
  ${maxWidth};
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: ${props => props.theme.colors.body50};
  ${defineWrapper}//  ERROR!
`;

const StyledDiv: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  return <Container>{children}</Container>;
};

StyledDiv.defaultProps = {
  // default props here
};

export default StyledDiv;
```